# Using jQuery or Ajax get function to pull in text from another page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

The short story is our CMS limits us to using solely html/js. I'm creating a dynamic graph page that has a lot of data that will be updated monthly. There is a separate php form on the server the staff member will fill out, that content is stored in the database, and there's another php file that displays the information. Jquery/Ajax needs to pull that info from the outside php page, which I've done on one other project. This difference this time is that I need to target specific sections of code to pull in, because the results will be going into a javascript variable for use in populating a graph.

With me so far? What I need jquery/ajax to do is target specific div ID's on the populating php page so I can direct it to the proper js variable.

I've looked at jston, but am not strong with JS, and thus that looks like Greek. Thoughts, Ideas, Suggestions?

EDIT:

I've tried this code:

```
$('#hiddenDiv').load('test.php #newdata');
```

Which imported nothing, even though there is text on the test.php page with a div with the id "newdata".

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: Any why don't you make a php file that displays just the info you need instead of making some sort of hack in the JavaScript layer?

Comment: So displaypage.html (within our CMS) has javascript code to display 2 graphs. There are roughly 10 parts to the graph that need to be updated dynamically based on the database. I need to update the javascript code on displaypage.html with some function grabbing the specific items and plugging them in. If I created the entire javascript code in php, how then can I pull it into the displaypage.html correctly?

Comment: @Treffynnon - The only code currently on that page is the hard coded graphs (using HighCharts). Any JavaScript lead I find I'm testing on another page though, so just looking for possible directions at this point, and which will give the best result.

Comment: @Casey as this is using Highcharts your PHP script should really be supplying an array structure of data that you can feed straight into the charting scripts as JSON.

Comment: @Treffynnon - I'm feeding in MUCH more than just the data points that will be plotted (chart axis, titles, etc) - Hence the "10 parts to the graph" that I posted above. I can have php display the entire JS code I need, but the issue is finding a piece of JS or Ajax that can grab everything on the php page and put it in the right place on the html page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery `load` function:

```
$('#loadIntoMe').load('somepage.php #onlyLoadMe');
```

If there is a space in the URL provided as a parameter to the `load` function, it's assumed to be a jQuery selector and is used to extract the specified elements, instead of returning the entire document. See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more information.

**Update** (based on comments)

To store the result in a variable, you could use a hidden `div` and a callback function:

```
var yourVariable;
$('#loadIntoMe').load('somepage.php #onlyLoadMe', function() {
    yourVariable = $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: This has some promise, but I'm not updating a DIV on the html page, I'm updating JavaScript code. How would I change the "#loadIntoMe" to reflect a JS variable?

Comment: You could update a hidden `div`, and use a callback function to get the content of the `div` into a JS variable when the `load` is completed.

Comment: Okay, where can I find a tutorial or information on how to do that?

Comment: Just saw that. Here's my Javascript:

**JS

var yourVariable;
   $('#hidden').load('test.php #data', function() {
       yourVariable = $(this).html();
   });


I have a hidden div on that page with #id of "hidden", and on my php page the div's ID is "newdata". The variable doesn't seem to be pulling in any info (document.write came up empty).

Comment: Well if you've copied your code correctly in your comment, that would be because you are looking for an element with `id` "data" in the loaded page, but you said the `div` in question has `id` "newdata".

Comment: Copied Incorrectly. var yourVariable;
   $('#hidden').load('test.php #newdata', function() {
       yourVariable = $(this).html();
       document.write(yourVariable);
   });  -  Should also add that I've tried it with both numerical and text values, neither yielded a result..

Answer (score 0):

All javascript graphing libraries I have employed have required a javascript object to be passed to them. In this instance I would be use jQuery `$.get` to get a `json_encode`d set of data.

**PHP**

```
<?php
header('Conent-type: application/json');
$array_of_data = array(
    'axes1' => array( // data goes here
    ),
    // etc and so on
);
echo json_encode($array_of_data);
?>
```

**JS**

```
$.getJSON('/url/to/php.php', function(data) {
    // console.log(data);
    // generate graph from data
});
```

Comment: As I posted, I'm not overly familiar with JS, and the json functions are far above my head. Do you have a link to a good tutorial on how to implement? The way php is displaying the json code doesn't seem helpful in the least (most likely because I have no idea what I'm looking at).

Comment: Try http://google.com . You aren't supposed to be looking at the JSON coming from the PHP directly, but through the jQuery $.getJSON method I mentioned above. Open up your firebug in Firefox to the console tab and un-comment my console.log() line above.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but as I said, I have little to no JS experience, and JSON seems a bit too advanced. Even with firebug, I don't have the experience using the "script" tab.